# Meaning of ところがある in this weather forecast

Tags: grammar

How can ところがある be translated in this sentence?

> 今夜から明日にかけてに大雨になるところがあるでしょう。

And 大雨になる? It means "is going to rain"?

Comment: We do not say 「あるです」.

Comment: @l'électeur not even on paper?

Comment: @ChristineLala No, but this could be a separate question — your question about ところがある received an answer. If you're still wondering why you can say あるでしょう but not あるです, maybe you can ask a different question.

Answer (score 2):

The literal translation of ところがある would be something like "there are places". When the phrase is used for weather forecasting, it means the rain is not widespread but isolated. 大雨になる means "is going to rain", yes, but since it's with 大, the phrase suggests the rain will be heavy.